# how to change video fps/bitrate from backend side after uploading using node js means it should change live from 144p to 240p, in video

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ffmpeg, fastify

how to change video fps/bitrate from backend side after uploading using node js  means it should change live from 144p to 240p means it should goes up to down in all quality, in video

> Blockquote

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use ffmpeg to resize and change bitrate

```
ffmpeg -i input_video.mp4 -vf "scale=426:240" -b:v 10M output_video.mp4
```